# Search contents of locally saved emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, network-shares

We're having a bit of a mailbox cleanup and one of the problems we're trying to resolve is the ability to search the contents of emails once they are saved on a network drives.

We don't want to be using local archives or online archives.

This is inline with how the company works (don't ask) however until they can search the contents of email in a network drive this is going to be a an issue.

We don't want to be using paid software as the company is quite tight on it's IT budget.

Thanks

Comment: Check into roaming profiles with folder redirection. This will make sure there are no local copies of any OSTs and if you are hosting exchange yourself, should be ok.

Comment: Thanks @Narzard this is actually the reason we want to move emails (for some users) as we want to introduce roaming profiles. Unfortunately we use O365 so it's not hosted locally.

Comment: What format do you use for locally saved email files?

Comment: @thims the standard outlook format.